# motor inrush current in reduced voltage starter

Tags: power-supply, motor

Reduced voltage starters reduce both voltage and inrush current i.e. the start-up power is reduced.

But, during normal operation, a reduction in voltage would cause an increase in current.

How the same motor behaves differently i.e. during starting the current reduces due to voltage reduction, but in steady-state a reduction of voltage will cause an increase in current?

Comment: imagine a 1 speed bicycle with no coaster (direct chain drive). Starting Torque = current I = V/DCR ( coil R)  When RPM increases impedance of coil inductance increases (Z=2pi f L) so I reduces. At the same time if you stop peddling the bike peddles will keep turning. this is the self -generating back EMF.  This is an increase in current but in the opposite direction now as a generator instead of a motor load

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75, you mean 'pedals' and 'pedalling' - with 'peddling', you've spoke about flogging stuff on the street :-)

Comment: Since the question is tagged [power-supply] and [motor], the answer by @Tony Stewart seems appropriate.  I suspect that the appropriate tags may be [induction motor] and [motor controller]. For that case, the answer would be quite different.